# How to disable (red) warning when adding preview extension to Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am adding extension `azure-devops` to Azure CLI using the following command:

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

Because this extension is in preview it gives me a red warning when I run it from my installation scripts:

> WARNING: The installed extension 'azure-devops' is in preview.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: The in... is in preview.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>       + PSComputerName        : mycomputer.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Is there any way to prevent this warning?

Comment: `2 > /dev/null` ?

Comment: Normally warnings are displayed in yellow text,warnings are displayed in red..Are you sure you are seeing warning ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar As you see its text say "WARNING" and I see red color on the console. Otherwise it installs and works without error

Comment: @4c74356b41: yes 2> is always an option, but I would like to see if something really goes wrong...

Comment: Try to run the Azure CLI commands in CMD instead of ISE or Powershell, is there still the same red warning?

Comment: @NancyXiong I must run it as a PowerShell script

Comment: @NancyXiong That is a good suggestion, and worth writing in as an answer. Even if the main script must be powershell, the 'az extension add' part can be executed in a previous task by CMD, in which case the warning is suppressed.